# Error al hacer Group By en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla la cual contiene los lugares donde han estado distintas personas, estoy intentando obtener el último lugar en dónde estuvo cada una de esas personas en una sola tabla, para ello estoy agrupando por IdEmpleado y buscando la fecha mayor, esos dos datos si los obtengo de manera correcta, el problema es que las demás columnas no corresponden a las que estoy intentando obtener. Dejo imagenes de mi tabla y de mi consulta. Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

[image: Tabla de todos los datos]

[image: Mi consulta erronea, el idEmpleado 1, debe tener como area Estado de México y tiene Oaxaca]

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Oswuell el error es que el Empleado con Id 1 viajó por última vez el 03/09/2018 a Estado de México, sin embargo en mi consulta me sale que visitó Oaxaca, sé que algo estoy haciendo mal pero no encuentro que es

Comment: ¿Podrías poner una captura de la tabla o tablas indicando los campos a filtrarse?

Comment: Algo raro hay en tu tabla, puedes mostrar lo que arroja un **`SHOW CREATE TABLE tblMovimientos`** ?

Comment: Carlos por favor quita los campos **Id** y **area**  para ver como se comporta

Comment: Hola Carlos, encontraste cual era el problema?